# When to use which WCF binding

Tags: wcf-binding

I know there are total 9 binding in WCF.
Generally i use http and TCP binding. 
My question is, how will i know which binding should i use in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Juval Lowy](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx) has a good decision tree diagram on this blog [here](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/03/31/wcf-binding-decision.aspx)